# Covert Character from Upper case to lower and Lower case to upper in C language? Answer

Tags: c

The answer is underwritten. Best of Luck. This is for beginners especially.
At first, we declare the variables so we can start.

#include <stdio.h>

```
int main() {
    char u,l,i, A,B;
 
    printf("Choose any conversion A. Upper to Lower or B. Lower to Upper");
    scanf("%c", &i);

    switch (i) {
    case 'A':
        printf("Write down the character");
        scanf("%c", &u);
        u = u - 32;
        printf("The lower character is %c", u);
    case 'B':      
        printf("Write down the character");
        scanf("%c", &l);
        l = l - 32;
        printf("The Upper character is %c", l);
    break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. We like the code to be included in the question so we can try to run/fix it. Also, you should say explicitly what doesn't work about your code. Also, please pick the language you are using (C is not C++). All that said, the most obvious problem you might be having is the missing `break` after the first `case`, so if the user chooses `A`, the second conversion will run as well.

Comment: `scanf()` leave a newline in the stream later consumed by your next `scanf()` call.

Comment: It turns out that `scanf` is a terrible function, and `%c` is one of its most terrible conversion specifiers.  Eventually you'll want to learn how to read input without either.  For now, though, just use `" %c"` -- note the space before the `%`.

Comment: `value = (char >= 'A' && char <= 'Z') ? char + 32 : ((char >= 'a' && char <= 'z') ? char - 32 : char);`

Comment: Don't use magic numbers like 32. C has functions tolower and toupper, use them.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a trailing new line left at the end of the stream which `scanf` consumes as a character. Add a space before the `%c` to consume the trailing whitespace:

```
scanf(" %c", &i);
```

Also, there are other problems with your code, like the first `case` of your switch statement lacks a `break;` statement. And to convert from upper to lower, you have to add `32` instead of subtracting:

```
switch (i) {
    case 'A':
        printf("Write down the character");
        scanf(" %c", &u);
        u = u + 32;
        printf("The lower character is %c", u);
        break;
    case 'B':      
        printf("Write down the character");
        scanf(" %c", &l);
        l = l - 32;
        printf("The Upper character is %c", l);
        break;
```

Adding and subtracting 32 for every character is an unpromising way to convert between cases. It will give unexpected results if the character to convert is already in the right case and for non-alphabets.
I'd rather use two functions and add the required checks:

```
char to_lowercase(char input) {
    if (input > 64 && input < 90) return input + 32;
    else return input; 
}
char to_uppercase(char input) {
   if(input > 96 && input < 123) return input - 32;
   else return input;
}
```

And this will change the `switch` as follows:

```
switch (i) {
    case 'A':
        printf("Write down the character");
        scanf(" %c", &u);
        printf("The lower character is %c", to_lowercase(u));
        break;
    case 'B':      
        printf("Write down the character");
        scanf(" %c", &l);
        printf("The Upper character is %c", to_uppercase(l));
        break;
```

Comment: Rather than _magic numbers_, consider `if (input >= 'A' && input <= 'Z") return input + ('a' - 'A');` or standard function `tolower()`.